# With Android 15 BAL hardening this activity start may be blocked if the PI creator upgrades target_sdk to 35+

Tags: android, android-activity

With Android 15 BAL hardening this activity start may be blocked if the PI creator upgrades target_sdk to 35+ AND the PI sender upgrades target_sdk to 34+! [callingPackage: com.android.shell; callingUid: 2000; callingPid: 8295; appSwitchState: 2; callingUidHasAnyVisibleWindow: false; callingUidProcState: CACHED_EMPTY; isCallingUidPersistentSystemProcess: false; forcedBalByPiSender: BSP.NONE; intent: Intent { act=android.intent.action.MAIN cat=[android.intent.category.DEFAULT] flg=0x10000000 cmp=com.vpn.enter/.SplashActivity }; callerApp: null; balAllowedByPiCreator: BSP.ALLOW_BAL; resultIfPiCreatorAllowsBal: BAL_ALLOW_PERMISSION; hasRealCaller: true; isPendingIntent: false; realCallingPackage: android.uid.shell:2000[debugOnly]; realCallingUid: 2000; realCallingPid: 8295; realCallingUidHasAnyVisibleWindow: false; realCallingUidProcState: CACHED_EMPTY; isRealCallingUidPersistentSystemProcess: false; originatingPendingIntent: null; realCallerApp: null; balAllowedByPiSender: BSP.ALLOW_FGS; resultIfPiSenderAllowsBal: BAL_ALLOW_PERMISSION]

Comment: What is your question?

Comment: I'll ask: What is "BAL hardening"? And can developers get permission to send PI (PendingIntent?) under these SDK conditions?

Comment: Answering my question: "BAL" is Background Activity Launch(ing). It is [mentioned in AOSP here](https://android.googlesource.com/platform/frameworks/base/+/master/services/core/java/com/android/server/wm/BackgroundActivityStartController.java?pli=1#501).